# How this Char Array should be? (A Tour For C++ example)

Tags: c++

In A Tour of C++ there is the following example:

```
int count_x(char∗ p, char x)
// count the number of occurrences of x in p[]
// p is assumed to point to a zero-ter minated array of char (or to nothing)
{
 int count = 0;

  while (p) 
  {
   if (∗p==x)
     ++count;
   ++p;
   }

return count;
}
```

Then I tested it but it doesn't work. Since it throws me a segmentation fault I supposed there is a problem with the array I'm using which is this one:

```
 char c_arr[11] {'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd'};
```

Anyone knows why does this happen?

Comment: If you found this code in a book, dispose of it immediately in an environmentally friendly way.  It's possible you didn't transcribe it correctly, but as shown, this code is garbage.

Comment: Short answer: `while(p)` should be `while(*p)` instead.

Comment: this char array should be encapsulated in a class with constructor and destructor and nice accessors, aka `std::string`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It's Bjarne Stroustrup's book, the code is badly copied and introduced the error.

Comment: What is the symbol between `char` and `p`: `∗`? It seems to be a unicode symbol which looks a little bit like the correct symbol `*`. Next to each other you will see a difference: `∗*`

Comment: A look in the book confirms that you misspelled `while (*p)` when you were copying the code. (The "Tour" isn't really a beginner's introduction, it's aimed at experienced programmers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int count_x(char∗ p, char x)
// count the number of occurrences of x in p[]
// p is assumed to point to a zero-ter minated array of char (or to nothing)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (p) // Error here
    {
        if (∗p==x)
            ++count;
        ++p;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The problem is `while (p)`. It does *not* check if p is pointing to a **zero character**, but checks if p is a **null pointer** instead. So it will (theoretically) never stop searching and of course, it will run into invalid memory addresses, receiving SIGSEGV (segmentation fault).

You can't put a null pointer at the end of the string because a null pointer is **a pointer pointing to address 0 (zero)**. "Null" is an attribute of the pointer itself and has nothing to do with *what* it's pointing to, only *where*.

To fix, use `while (*p)`. Then if p is pointing to `\0` (null character), it will give a falsy value to `while`, exiting the loop.

Comment: "receiving SIGSEGV (segmentation fault)." Is it inevitable that the program will seg fault?

Comment: @SchwiftyMcSchwifulface That's the most likely outcome in practice. Formally, the program exhibits undefined behavior, which means it can legally produce [any outcome whatsoever.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: @SchwiftyMcSchwifulface Quitting of a segmentation fault is the best result. It could have been worse by violating certain memory area's restrictions, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: But the book says that it's supposed to stop at the end of the array because it ends with a nullpointer, is there a way to put a nullpointer at the end of the array?

Comment: @JorgeRodríguez See edit. Don't be too stubborn. A book can have typos. Worse books may even have wrong content.

Comment: @iBug Yeah, you're right, it's just that I expected a lot more from a book of Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: @iBug And, by the way, you're right, that way it works, it just bugged me.

Answer (score -3):

```
// p is assumed to point to a zero-ter minated array of char (or to nothing)
```

Your array is not a C string: there must a 0 value at the end.
Your loop never stops as it doesn't find a 0 value.

-- EDIT --
The test performed by the loop is incorrect: the while instruction reads the address of p and not its value, so even though there was a 0 value in the array, the loop would not have stopped.

Comment: The loop never even checks for a 0 value, so it doesn't matter whether one is present.

Comment: Yes I stopped at the first error :-) I was so sure that the lines copied from the book were correctly copied, that I checked only his own code. There is an error with the test performed by the while as it tests the address and not the value.

Comment: I assume you mean the `while` *loop* not `for` *instruction*

Comment: Yes. Another typo :-(